# Detect SSL hash algorithm with Python

Tags: python, ssl, sha

Now that SHA-1 will be banned next year by major browsers, I want to detect which sites are still using it. Is there a way to get this information using Python (such as [Python's ssl library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html))? I can use `openssl s_client` but I'd prefer a Pythonic solution (that is compatible with my async framework).

s_client example:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect winkel.vpro.nl:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep -i sha
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

I dug through the ssl docs but couldn't find hash algo references. And I don't know how to get this info from the ssl context. TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature hash algorithm is not a property of the SSL connection but a property of the certificate. Once you have the certificate you can get the algorithm using [get_signature_algorithm](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_signature_algorithm) from OpenSSL.crypto:

```
import ssl, socket, OpenSSL

# connect to server and get certificate as binary (DER)
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('www.google.com',443))
sslsock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
cert_der = sslsock.getpeercert(True)

# load binary certificate and get signature hash algorithm
cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert_der)
print cert.get_signature_algorithm()
# -> 'sha256WithRSAEncryption'
```

With Python3 one can also use [signature_hash_algorithm](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.Certificate.signature_hash_algorithm) from the cryptography package:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

... get cert_der the same way as before ...
cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert_der, default_backend())
print(cert.signature_hash_algorithm.name)
#  -> 'sha256'
```